# How to use tee command of MySQL in shellscript?

Tags: mysql

I'm having a file mytest.sql file and it contains following statements:

```
use test;   
tee output123.log;   
select database() as 'Database';   
select now() as 'Start Time';   
set autocommit=0;   
insert into table1 values(3,'k');   
insert into table1 values(4,'kk');   
insert into table1 values(5,'kkk');   
commit;   
select * from table1;   
notee;
```

`$mysql -h localhost -u root -p < mytest.sql`

output of log file:

[image]

When i login to MySQL  and execute the statements I'm getting the output in the below format :

[image]

output of log file :

[image]

I need the same above output when the statements are executed from shell script. how to do it .

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `--table` option to `mysql`.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysqlsh.html#option_mysqlsh_table notes "batch mode" specifically; `mysql` is probably inferring that `--table` should be on if the input device is a terminal and off otherwise, a common mechanism for such programs.

Comment: after using --table --verbose it is fine but not shoiwng i row inserted .how to get one row inserted statement also .

Comment: `-v` should work for that, says https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/batch-mode.html